# Return data from screen with .pop()

Tags: flutter

In screenA, I have a text string and button with onTap event like this:

```
      String onScreenA;
      void initState(){
       super.initState();
       onScreenA = "";
       setState(() {}); 
      }
      onTap: () {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => ScreenB(),
        );           
      },
```

ScreenB

```
            new FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              
              Navigator.of(context).pop("ValueFromB");
            },
            child: new Text("ValueFromB"))
```

It's mean when I onTap button on `screenA`. It will goto `screenB`. When user onTap `FlatButton` in `ScreenB`, it will return back `screenA` and set `String onScreenA = "ValueFromB"`.

How can I do that?

Comment: can you show us more code of your screenB return Widget?

Comment: @Reign Thanks for your answer. It's basically a button with value String or number like my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `onTap`, `await` for the result of `showDialog` and assign it to `onScreenA`.

```dart
onTap: () async {
  onScreenA = await showDialog(
    context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => ScreenB(),
    );           
},
```

The [`showDialog`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html) function returns a `Future` that resolves with the value passed to `pop`, so just handle the `Future` and assign the result as you want.